# How to calculate or approximate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)dx$

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, approximation, integral

$\sigma(x)$ is the sigmoid function, that is, $\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$. And $x$ is from a Normal distribution of 0 mean and 1 variance. Now I'd like to calculate the expectation of the derivative value of the sigmoid function, i.e,

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)dx$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Monte Carlo will work. You can generate variables from the standard normal distribution, plug them into $\sigma(x) \left(1-\sigma(x)\right)$ and take the average.

Comment: People are suggesting Monte Carlo which will work but is generally a terrible idea for a $1D$ integral. Use numerical integration or (adaptive) quadrature, it is much better/faster for low dimensions (up to $D=3$, if I remember correctly; from $D=4$, the scaling of the error of numerical integration and Monte Carlo becomes the same).

Comment: @lacerbi Thanks for your comment! Indeed I also prefer numerical approach. Do you have any good idea? Thanks!

Comment: Here I would just do a brutal integration via Simpson's rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule
As for the bounds, go as far as you want in terms of SDs of the normal integral (presumably five or six SDs are more than enough).
I would not recommend Gauss-Hermite quadrature here because the other piece of the integrand (besides the normal) is probably not well approximated by a polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica doesn't give an analytic result, but it does give the numerical result 0.206621.

If you want some sort of semi-analytic treatment, you can expand
$$\sigma(x) ( 1 - \sigma(x) ) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{x^4}{96} + \cdots$$
and then integrate term by term to get
$$\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \cdots$$
The first three terms get you to 0.22. If you can write the $n$th term of the expansion in closed form, you might even be able to recognize the term-by-term integrated series as related to some established function or constant.

Comment: The power series approach is mathematically invalid, because the radius of convergence of this power series for $\sigma$ is just $\pi$.  I believe your method works approximately, and that only because most of the Normal probability is concentrated within the radius of convergence and $\sigma$ is bounded.  In short, it looks like you got lucky. With more careful analysis, you could estimate the error and justify this approach as an approximate calculation.

Comment: @whuber: It's a fair point, but it's more that just luck -- it's an asymptotic series. More exactly, if you introduce a width parameter for the Gaussian $s$, it's an asymptotic series in $s$. For $s=1$, the terms get down to $\sim 0.02$ before they start growing, so that's the accuracy limit. And the fact that it's asymptotic doesn't prevent it being Borel summable, so the route to a fully closed-form solution isn't closed by the divergence.

Comment: I am unable to make much sense of those remarks, David, for two reasons.  First, I don't see any connection between your "$s$" and the function $\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))$. Second, I understand "asymptotic" to mean that when you truncate the series at a fixed number of terms, then as $x$ grows large the truncated series grows arbitrarily close to the true value, relative to the true value.  But the opposite holds: no matter where you truncate it, it will *diverge* for large $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on JohnK's comment: You want to find the expectation of a function with respect to a standard normal distribution. Since it seems difficult to evaluate the integral, we can instead resort to estimating it using Monte Carlo.

If we sample $x_1, x_2, \dots x_N$ from a $N(0,1)$ distribution, then your quantity can be estimated by 
$$\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma(x_i) (1 - \sigma(x_i)\,. $$

As you increase $N$, you can an increasingly better estimate of the quantity. The R code below returns the value .20669 with standard error .00015.

```
> set.seed(100)
> sig <- function(x)
+ {
+   1/(1+exp(-x))
+ }
> 
> N <- 1e5
> samples <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
> mean(sig(samples)*(1 - sig(samples)))
[1] 0.2066863

> # The standard error of the mean estimate
> sd(sig(samples)*(1 - sig(samples)))/sqrt(N)
[1] 0.0001463474
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, note that
$$
\sigma(x)\{1-\sigma(x)\} = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} = \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right)'
$$
Thus, integrating by part,
$$
\int \sigma(x)\{1-\sigma(x)\}N(0,1)dx = \left[\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} N(0,1)(x)\right] - \int \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} N(0,1)' dx
$$
The $[...]$ term equals 0. Then
$$
N(0,1)' = - x N(0,1)
$$
Finally, if my calculations are correct, your integral is
$$
\int \frac{x}{1+e^{-x}}N(0,1)dx
$$
Applying the Monte Carlo technique, generate $x_1,\ldots,x_n \sim N(0,1)$ and compute then average 
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{1+e^{-x_i}}
$$ 
It might be more stable [not even sure], though pretty much equivalent to JohnK and GreenPaker's suggestions.

Comment: Given that the Monte Carlo experiment is a few lines of code, could you run the comparison in term of (estimated) standard error for both Monte Carlo approaches?

Comment: The integration by parts is a nice idea.  It doesn't seem to help though: it replaces an exponentially decreasing function by one that linearly increases.  That likely makes the integral a little bit harder to evaluate numerically.